# For each java class, output the contributing tests (which cover that class) to a JSON report

Tags: java, code-coverage, clover

The HTML report in open-clover includes a Contributing Tests section which identifies which tests covered the class in question. I would like to be able to generate a JSON report whereby this information is directly provided; that would make it much simpler to leverage in other tooling.

Alternatively, if there's some other open-source coverage tool that does this I would also be interested.